# Filter view in SharePoint Add-In based on specific user

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I want to filter my list based on Current User and filter another view based on the Manager.

To filter for current user i used this :

```
<Query>
  <OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Name="Modified"
              Ascending="FALSE">
    </FieldRef>
  </OrderBy>
  <Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="Author" />
      <Value Type="Integer">
        <UserID />
      </Value>
    </Eq>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

To filter based on another user which is not the current one , what type of field should i use ? I have the login name of the user and email. Do i need to get somehow the id and compare it with UserID ? What type is UserID?

Answer (score 0):

Filter based on User ID:

```
<Query> 
   <Where> 
      <Eq> 
         <FieldRef Name='SlaesPerson' LookupId='true' /> 
         <Value Type='User'>7</Value> 
      </Eq> 
   </Where> 
</Query>
```

Filter based on user name:

```
<Query> 
   <Where> 
      <Eq> 
         <FieldRef Name='SalesPerson' /> 
         <Value Type='User'>john</Value> 
      </Eq> 
   </Where> 
</Query>
```

Reference here:

http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.sg/2009/11/sharepoint-user-idname-in-spquery.html

Caml designer is good tool for caml.
[image]